# Why intensity of unpolarised light is halved each time it passes through a polariser?

Tags: optics, waves, polarization

My doubt is

> Why is intensity halved each time an unpolarised light passes through a polaroid?

My thought process is that if an unpolarised light passes through a polaroid, it will polarise the incoming light and we will have a polarised light with half of initial intensity.

And if the same light is passed through the polaroid parallel to the first one, it should not reduce the intensity of light by half again.

Because, according to Malus law, the intensity of polarised light is given by $$I=I_o cos^2\theta$$

So, why do we have to halve the intensity for every polaroid through which the light has passed through?

This question was inspired by this test question [image]

Comment: Where did you read that we have to halve the intensity each time?

Comment: @Ruslan My teacher asked a question in the test which I got wrong. So I asked him about it and he told me that if an unpolarised light passes through the polariser, then the intensity becomes half. I can attach a photo of that question if you want it.

Comment: Your description of the situation is correct. Either you misunderstood your teacher is wrong. Note also that if polarized light passes through a polarizer that is oriented at 45 degrees relative to the polarization of the light, this also reduces the intensity by a factor of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intensity of *unpolarized* light is halved when it passes through a polarizing filter (note that this assumes a perfect filter - in practice the exact proportion of light passed may be somewhat less than half, depending on the design of the filter).

The intensity of *polarized* light passing through a polarizing filter depends on the angle between the polarization of the incident light and the direction of the filter, according to Malus's law (again, this assumes a perfect filter).

We can't comment on your test question without seeing exactly how it was worded.

**Update**

Now that you have posted the original question then your problem is clearer. There is already a more detailed answer elsewhere, but in summary the maximum amplitude (when the angle between filters P and Q is $\frac \pi 4$) is $\frac {I_0} 8$ because:

- the intensity of the unpolarized light passing through filter P is reduced by a factor of $\frac 1 2$ because this is the *average* value of $\cos^2 \theta$
- the intensity of the polarized light passing through filter Q is reduced by another factor of $\frac 1 2$ because this is the value of $\cos^2 \theta$ when $\theta = \frac \pi 4$, which is the angle between filters P and Q
- the intensity of the polarized light passing through filter R is reduced by a third factor of $\frac 1 2$ because this is the value of $\cos^2 \theta$ when $\theta = \frac \pi 4$, which is the angle between filters Q and R

Comment: Here is the photo of the test question [link](https://imgur.com/a/BVvzDEA)

Answer (score 0):

In the test question the arrangement of the polarizers is such that the unpolarized incident light is incident on P, after which it becomes polarized with half the initial intensity. Then this light gets analyzed at Q, getting reduced according to the Malus' law.

The light going out of Q is also polarized, but the polarization is rotated with respect to P. This light then goes into R, which again analyzes the polarization, but with respect to an axis perpendicular to that of P. To get the intensity of the result you need to once again apply Malus' law, taking into account the rotation of polarization direction by Q and by R. After this you'll get a product of two cosines with different arguments.

Now, you can solve this without any calculations at all. For this, try to intuitively understand that the maximal transmission of this PQR system will be when the Q polarizer is rotated at 45° with respect to both P and R. At least, it's easy to see that this angle is between 0° and 90° just from the fact that at angles of 0° and 90° there's no transmission, while somewhere between them there must be some. Thus, the right answer is either 2 or 3. Now, given that Malus' law contains a square of cosine, rather than absolute value, there can't be a cusp in the curve where it touches zero, the curve must be smooth there (just as $y=x^2$ is smooth at $x=0$), so the answer 3 can be discarded, and we are left with the final answer 2.

To get the *amplitude* of the resulting intensity curve you need to just apply the Malus' law twice and remember to halve the initial polarizer's input to yield

\begin{equation}
I=I_0\overbrace{\frac12}^{\text{P}}\overbrace{\cos^2\theta}^{\text{Q}}\;\overbrace{\cos^2\left(\frac\pi2+\theta\right)}^{\text{R}}=\frac{I_0}8\sin^2(2\theta).
\end{equation}

Comment: But this doesn't answer my primary question.

Comment: @satyamsingh but this follows from what I said about application of Malus' law. I've updated the answer with an explicit derivation.